# How to find specific item in a Python dict within another dict?

Tags: python

Let's say I have a Python dictionary that looks like the one below:

```
sample_dict = {'Grade': {'Aya':4.0, 'John':3.0, 'Anna':1.0},
     'Address': {'Aya':'California', 'John':'Canada', 'Anna':'Mexico'},
     'School': 'Harvard University',
     'Nationality':{'Aya':'Japanese', 'John':'American', 'Anna':'American'}
    }
```

I'm quite confused how I could manipulate the code where I'll just pass down the parameter to search *e.g. Aya* and it will result to something like below:

```
Grade: Aya: 4.0
Address: Aya:California
School: Harvard University
Nationality: Aya: Japanese
```

Better yet:

```
Aya
Grade: 4.0
Address: California
School: Harvard University
Nationality: Japanese
```

Here's what I've started out:

```
def get_info(name):
    for key, value in sample_dict:
        print(name)
        if type(value) is dict:
            for people, equivalent in value:
                if(equivalent[name]):
                    print key, equivalent[name] 
                else:
                    print ("Not Found!")
        else:
            print key, value[key]
```

> > {'Grade': {'John': 3.0, 'Aya': 4.0, 'Anna': 1.0}, 'Nationality': {'John': 'American', 'Aya': 'Japanese', 'Anna': 'American'}, 'School':
> >     'Harvard University', 'Address': {'John': 'Canada', 'Aya':
> >     'California', 'Anna': 'Mexico'}}
>
> ---
>
> ValueError Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>        19             print key, value[key]
>        20 
>   ---> 21 get_info('Aya')
>
> in get_info(name)
>         8 
>         9 def get_info(name):
>   ---> 10     for key, value in sample_dict:
>        11         print(name)
>        12         if type(value) is dict:
>
> ValueError: too many values to unpack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sample_dict = {'Grade': {'Aya':4.0, 'John':3.0, 'Anna':1.0},
     'Address': {'Aya':'California', 'John':'Canada', 'Anna':'Mexico'},
     'School': 'Harvard University',
     'Nationality':{'Aya':'Japanese', 'John':'American', 'Anna':'American'}
    }

def get_info(name):
    _info = {}
    for key, val in sample_dict.items():
        try:
            if isinstance(val, dict):
                val = val[name]
            _info[key] = val
        except KeyError:
            return None
    return _info
```

Answer (score 3):

There's a lot of potential pitfalls here, but absent much more detail about what assumptions can be made about the data, you could satisfy this specific case with a one-line dict comprehension:

```
{k:(v['Aya'] if 'Aya' in v else v) for k,v in sample_dict.items()}
```

Comment: What if you'd look for someone named 'Harv' ;)

Comment: @JanZeiseweis Yep, hence the disclaimer. We weren't given much of any detail on how to generalize the data, so I took a fairly narrow interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

It should be as simple as using a function like this:

```
def get_info(name):
    print(name, '\n'
                'Grade:', sample_dict['Grade'][name], '\n'
                'Address:', sample_dict['Address'][name], '\n'
                'School:', sample_dict['School'], '\n'
                'Nationality:', sample_dict['Nationality'][name])
```

Then using any of your names in the function works like you wanted:

```
get_info('Aya')

Aya
Grade: 4.0
Address: California
School: Harvard University
Nationality: Japanese
```

Comment: I should note that in the example dictionary, there is no name association with the School entry, so the function doesn't actually check that entry using the name. If you ever changed the dictionary to specify school by name, like in the other dictionary entries, you would just need to add [name] into the function's School print line, such as print('School:', sample_dict['School'][name])